# Size of a folder on server

Tags: linux, cpanel

I have a magento store running on a shared hosting server. We are in process of migrating the site and need to know the size of particular folders like **media** etc.

This will help us getting the size of backup file in reasonable proportion. Right now the back file is almost 6 GB :-(   So its just not possible to download and upload the same.

If I know the size of individual folders, I can leave some of the bigger ones for the time being.

Please let me know how can I know this. Our server has cPanel.

Comment: HAve you tried with `ll`??

Comment: whats ll ??.... I have no idea about this.

Comment: when you are at folder you want and in terminal you type `ll` and hit `enter` it will display a lot of info, like permissions, type of file, and size, but I don't know if it is what you want

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: `ll` is just a frequent alias to `ls -l`. It doesn't show directory sizes, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `du -hs /path/to/store/*` to calculate sizes of all subfolders directly under `/path/to/store`.

Comment: Where should I run this command.